# Excel to SQL upload operations?

Tags: c#, sql, excel

I can fetch the data from Excel sheet to SQL Database, using File upload tool in `c#`.

My excel sheet & datatable have only 3 columns like `name`, `address`, `phone number`.
I can upload more than 5 times with same excel sheet. After this operation I am gonna open my SQL database, its shows the 3 fields are continuously adding the same table repeatedly.

my question is..

1. How to avoid this adding same data in same table.
2. How to check insert data is already exists in table or not?
3. Update only particular field in table, when I upload the excel sheet have any one field change.

Answer (score 0):

Excel is doing this.

If you upload your data by vba function it wil refresh after row [added, deleted, filtred].
Had same issue. Make a CSV file and use SQL Coursor to add data line by line.

Answer (score 0):

First upload the data to temptable , then use

the below insert ststement

INSERT INTO ActualTAble (Col1,Col2,Col3)

SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3

FROM TempTable INNER JOIN ActualTable

ON ActualTable.Col1 = TempTable.Col1

WHERE 'Give your condition if necessary'